# Send an SMS to Ubuntu Server to Run Scripts/Commands?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, smartphone, sms

I was wondering if there was a way to have a text message sent to a number (or email) that an Ubuntu computer could read, and that message would act as a command for the computer?

An example might be this: I'm running late to and I need my work computer to have `program` on itself for a meeting when I get there. I send a text containing `sudo apt-get install program` to the computer, and when I arrive everything will be downloaded.

Direct access to the terminal via text might not be possible or too risky, but would running bash/bin scripts be possible?

I've seen articles on this topic such as [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-issue-a-command-to-your-computer-with-a-text-message/) 
that involve external programs like [IF](https://ifttt.com/) to get the message to the computer, but involve cellular data, local wifi, or outdated software with limited use. Is there any way send the texts to the designated ready to go computer, with nothing but a sms text from my phone?

Comment: You can install an ssh server and connect with your phone (over the internet) to the system.